# How to stop hiding v-drawer Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, swap

I have this code:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="open" :style="{ 'width': '122px', 'background-color': '#16181A' }" width="122px"
:color="theme.currentTheme.drawer" :mini-variant="!showSubNavigation" :floating="!showSubNavigation" clipped app>
<v-row class="fill-height" no-gutters>
  <v-navigation-drawer :style="{ 'width': '122px', 'background-color': '#16181A' }" :color="theme.currentTheme.drawer"
    mini-variant :value="open">
    <div v-show="isMobileViewport" :style="`height: ${$globals.HEADER_HEIGHT}px;`" class="app-icon">
      <router-link to="/" />
    </div>
```

After swap the menu is hiding away, but I need to keep it on the page. Please advise, how to keep it on the page ?

Comment: There's a severe lack of detail. More explanation of your code is needed. What do you mean exactly, "swap"?  What is being swapped?  there are also **two** navigation drawers.  How are they working together? Which one are you talking about that needs to stay open?  You should include all relevant code, including  any JS code that defines or affects the template code in question.  The HTML by itself doesn't reveal that much. Please make sure to review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with additional information.